# why UIWebView should not be subclassed?

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiwebview

From the [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), The UIWebView class should not be subclassed.

I just want to know why. There is no more detail about this.

Because I met a memory out issue in my project, which create one extended UIWebView, which could cause memory out issue. Otherwise, just create the UIWebView instance will not  cause the issue.

That is why I want to address this problem and try to analyze more.

Thanks for the guy to give some comments in terms of the design pattern with MVC.
I hope to close this once get some comments for memory management. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS development works on MVC concept and V part which is View should be as generic as possible. If you write a custom view, when the model changes the view has to change as well. It becomes interlinked..This means the view cannot be reused, especially when a new UI comes out..Better to put the code in the controller portion...Key: Keep the view as generic as possible..